# Run a script after unattended-upgrades runs (e.g. to update rkhunter)

Tags: upgrade, unattended-upgrades, rkhunter

Hi I'd like to be able to auto update rkhunter when upgrades happen automatically, but I can't seem to find a way to do this. 
I'd not want this to happen after a manual install via apt-get though or anything, just when the auto updates occur. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Just a question: how do you have unattended upgrades set up ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) If you installed rkhunter via apt-get, I believe you need to enable [AutomaticSecurityUpdates](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates).

2) If you compiled & installed rkhunter from tar.gz, you need to run:

```
sudo rkhunter --versioncheck
```

However, I don't see how one can link this back to Ubuntu update process.

3) Now if by updating rkhunter you mean to update the signature database on updating Ubuntu packages as documented [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RKhunter):

> To run rkhunter --propupd, automatic after software updates, add the
>   line *APT_AUTOGEN="yes"* to **/etc/default/rkhunter** (this gets read by
>   /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90rkhunter)

Comment: Thanks @BogdanBiv, I hadn't seen the part about `APT_AUTOGEN="yes" ` in the docs.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 18, and I don't have `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90rkhunter`. What am I missing?